# Detecting preperiodic points

Tags: modular-arithmetic, dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics

In short, I need to prove whether I have preperiodic orbits or wandering orbits for some dynamical systems.

Not as short: Let $\phi$ be a rational map. Suppose we want to know if 0 is preperiodic under $\phi$. Of course if it were, were could iterate endlessly until finding some $i,j$ with $i\neq j$ and $\phi^i(0) = \phi^j(0)$, however if 0 is not preperiodic, we must find some way to detect this. There are height bounds, but they're very large (and I don't know if anyone's actually computed them yet, beyond just proving their existence..) so it would be nice to avoid that.

One method my supervisor and I have talked about, is reducing modulo some good prime $p$. Specifically, let $p$ be a prime of good reduction for $\phi$, and consider the reduced map $\tilde{\phi}$. If 0 is preperiodic under $\phi$, then it is not hard to see that it must also be preperiodic under $\tilde{\phi}$, so we can determine integers $k',n'$ such that $\tilde{\phi}^{k' + n'}(0) = \tilde{\phi}^{k'}(0)$. Moreover, it can be shown that $n'$ divides the period of 0 under $\phi$, and $k' \leq k$. My supervisor suggests there is a way that we can use this to show that 0 is either preperiodic or not, under $\phi$, but I don't see this.

My problem is, if 0 is preperiodic under $\phi$, there exists integers $k,n$ such that $\phi^{k+n} = \phi^k$, so summing everything up in this notation, we have

-$\tilde{\phi}^{k+n} = \tilde{\phi}^k$

-$\tilde{\phi}^{k'+n'} = \tilde{\phi}^{k'}$

-$n'|n$

-$k'\leq k$

where $n'$ and $k'$ are easy to compute (I will be dealing with small primes unless a magnificently horrible example arises, but I doubt this..) but I simply do not see any way of getting $k$ from this information. If I were to have a map $\phi$ such that it takes 100 000 iterations of 0 to get to a periodic point, yet the reduced map is periodic right away, the situation seems undetectable.

Any ideas? I feel like I must be missing something simple..

Filling in a few more details, if we have a periodic point $P$, there are results that say the period of $P$ under $\phi$ is a multiple of the period under $\tilde{\phi}$, so if we use a couple well chosen primes for reduction, our list of possible periods for $P$ will be small, and easy to check with a computer. Hence why we are attempting this approach. (Also, this comes from a question in arithmetic dynamics, if anyone feels the need for such a tag to be created.)

Thanks!

Comment: What about about $20$ well-chosen primes? As a bonus, procedure is then parallelizable.

Comment: Sure, but we still don't know what $k$ is, and so if we're dealing with a point that is not preperiodic, we won't be able to stop having gone "far enough". We'll just keep searching and searching..

Comment: Basically, without a notion of the size of $k$, this procedure will not work (I think?)

Comment: The suggestion was only about maybe radically speeding up the search. It can fail, if period is very large, or (by adding primes) can be turned into a possibly more efficient search than the usual one, but still a search.

Comment: Fair enough, unfortunately I'm pretty sure most, if not all of my cases, are non-preperiodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, what my supervisor had in mind was to show a point is not preperiodic, by showing none of the points in its orbit can be periodic. If we have a map $\phi$ and it's reduction at $p$, $\tilde{\phi}$, then if $\phi$ has a periodic point $z$ of period $n$, we know $\tilde{\phi}$ has $z$ as a periodic point, with period $n'$, where $n'$ divides $n$.

So, it's not full proof, but we can use multiple primes, say $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_m$ and test the period of the points in the orbit of 0 for each of the reduction maps at $p_i$, suppose the periods are $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m$. Then we know if there is a periodic point in the orbit of 0 under $\phi$, it must be a multiple of $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m$. In fact, the works of Li, Morton-Silverman, Narkiewicz, Pezda and Zieve combined tells us exactly what the multiples can be. These are sufficiently restrictive, so that (one hopes) using enough good primes will give contradictory periods (i.e., $n = 3$ from one prime and $n = 5$ from another prime means there is no $n$!)

Fortunately, this was enough for all my (10 000) cases, and 0 is not preperiodic in every case, as expected!

If anyone would like the explicit references, I can certainly pop them up here. Otherwise, if you have access to The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems by Joseph Silverman, it's the first theorem in section 2.6 (page 62).

Answer (score 3):

If 0 is not preperiodic, I agree that a finite number of primes can never prove that.   However, they might tell you that $k$ and $n$, if they exist, must be outlandishly large, 
which one can take as an indication that 0 is not preperiodic.

Comment: This is what I was concerned of :<